# Angularjs orderBy ( using default order with reverse and multiple fields)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I'm currently using the example provided on Angular's website for orderBy: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

and adjusted it to create this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LErNA/1/

```
<tr>
  <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=false;order('name', false)">Name</a>
    (<a href="" ng-click="order('-name',false)">^</a>)</th>
  <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('zone', reverse)">Zone</a></th>
  <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('area',reverse)">Area</a></th>
</tr>
```

Right now, the sorting seems to be fine for alphabetical sorting (and numbered sorting). I'd like though that when the 'Zone' is clicked, it orders that alphabetically, but the Area (which is a number) will also be ordered lowest first to highest. I don't really know where to begin to create this secondary sort order.

I did notice though, if I click on the 'Area', and sort that first, from lowest to highest (clicking twice):

Name (^)    Zone    Area
Mike    B   1
Julie   D   1
Jim A   1
Adam    C   1
Pete    C   2
Mary    A   2
Frank   B   2
John    A   3

THEN click 'Zone', from lowest to highest, the order is the way I want it (clicking twice):

Name (^)    Zone    Area
Jim A   1
Mary    A   2
John    A   3
Mike    B   1
Frank   B   2
Adam    C   1
Pete    C   2
Julie   D   1

I hope that makes sense. Please let me know if it doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi please check link to jsfiddle

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that!

Comment: So when you click zone do you want to sort friends by zone and then by are or ... ?

Comment: Thats correct! If you click Zone, it will sort by Zone and also reference Area if the Zone is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanat to crate sorting by then by then by you need to create array of properties like in this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ty7Tp/

```
  <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order(['zone', 'area'],reverse)">Zone</a></th>
```